# send file from hyperledger fabric to IPFS

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, ipfs

Is it possible to send a file from hyperledger fabric smart contract (.go file type). To an private IPFS storage somehow?

I do not want this: client -> smart contract (hyperledger). and then
                    client -> IPFS storage

But I want this: client -> smart contract (hyperledger) -> IPFS storage

This comes in handy when you want to know exactly who uploaded a file or downloaded one.

I just want to know if it is possible thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in restriction from making an external call from within the chaincode, but I would not recommend the workflow you have described.

Chaincode runs on multiple peers, and in production you will most likely (and absolutely should) have an endorsement policy that requires multiple peers to endorse a transaction proposal. This means several peers will receive the request from the client and in turn make requests to your IPFS storage. If a successful upload to IPFS is a requirement for an endorsement proposal to be successful, you will either end up with multiple uploads to IPFS or failed transactions since the same file/descriptor is trying to be written to your storage.

The 'client -> chaincode -> client -> ordering service -> client -> IPFS storage' workflow is better option here. Managing knowledge of who uploads/downloads the file should be handled elsewhere. As a rule chaincodes should be as simple, efficient, and deterministic.